# What is the difference between VGroup container and Group container with nested VerticalLayout in fle4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am a beginner for flex. Now i am trying samples using the layout.

See the following scenario,

```
<s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center">
     <s:Label text="VGroup Container"/>
     <s:Button label="One"/>
     <s:Button label="Two"/>
     <s:Button label="Three"/>
</s:VGroup>

<s:Group>
     <s:layout>
           <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
     </s:layout>
     <s:Label text="Group with VerticalLayout"/>
     <s:Button label="One"/>
     <s:Button label="Two"/>
     <s:Button label="Three"/>
</s:Group>
```

Is it having any differences? If it's having, please share it with me. Otherwise tell me which one is better or which one is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are equivalent, mostly...

In general if I know the group layout orientation I'll use VGroup/HGroup rather than Group and layout, but that's just my preference, I don't think there's a significant performance difference.

I have places where I need to change orientation, so I'll use Group and change the layout based on the orientation state.  VGroup/HGroup won't let you change the layout associated with them.

Comment: Thank you Bill Turner. Now i have another one question. we can't make orientation changes in VGroup/HGroup or we won't? Sorry for this chilly  question. But i just want to know. Thank you.

Comment: Can't change - the setter for layout in VGroup and HGroup is overridden to prevent changing.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill Turner.